# onClick function with parameter in redux "presentation" component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is the best way to pass an object as argument to a function in a redux "presentation component"?

I have a `<BookList />` container component. Inside the BookList I render a `<BookListRow/>` presentation component for each book.

I want to make a button in each BookListRow to remove the book. So I do this:

```
const BookListRow = ({book, deleteBook}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                onClick={() => {deleteBook(book}}
        >
          <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td><a href={book.watchHref} target="_blank">Watch</a></td>
      <td><Link to={'/book/' + book.id}>{book.title}</Link></td>
      <td>{book.authorId}</td>
      <td>{book.category}</td>
      <td>{book.length}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

This works! But I read that it is best to avoid arrow functions in JSX because of bad performance. So what is a better way?

Comment: Pass the onClick function down instead by binding it in `mapDispatchToprops` or `mergeProps` if you need the `stateProps`.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson: I don't see how this would change how deleteBook() is passed down to BookListRow... Can you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: Since `deleteBook` is already defined, why not use directly 

`onClick="deleteBook({book})"`

just a thought

Comment: Arrow functions have less perfomance than normal functions? Sounds strange to me

Comment: @bluehipy: Because then the function is executed when the line is compiled. I only want it executed when ever the button is clicked.

Comment: @Borjante: No, but react creates a new instance of the function every time the view/component is rendered. That's why its bad practice to declare inline functions in jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class component:

```
class BookListRow extends React.Component {
  onBtnClick = () => {
    this.props.deleteBook(this.props.book);
  };

  render () {
    return (
      ...
        onClick={this.onBtnClick}
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

If you want to use stateless functional components, I think you can use memoization to optimize

I wrote a very simple proof of concept here: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/NpwLRE?editors=0011

The real onclick function will be declared only once. We save them to a `Map` so that every time the parent component re-renders, we can reuse them.

The example above is just a very simple PoC. It only works if the `onClick` method passed from parent will not change dynamically.

There are some memoization libraries, like https://github.com/caiogondim/fast-memoize.js

Comment: I guess this could be a solution. But it just dont feel right. I mean, BookListRow is more a presentation/state less component just rendering each row in the list. I would like to place all logic in the topmost container component.

Comment: It is doing the same thing: `onClick={() => {deleteBook(book}}`. There is no extra logic added

Comment: Oh yeah I get it. Seems to work. Sorry I'm just learning react and redux :) 
But it's not possible to keep BookListRow as a "dumb" component?

Comment: I think it is possible. You can memoize the derived methods

Comment: What does that mean?